# How to set color of the Button with jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have two buttons in my HTML page. I have added jQuery UI themes into my page. Still, my buttons have different color. Top place Button inheriting the color from jQuery UI whereas down place is from the custom body CSS defined in the page.

Here is my HTML for both Buttons:

```
<button id="housekeeping" style="float:left; margin-left:30px">HouseKeeping</button>
<button id="Front Desk" style="margin-left:178px; margin-top:0px">Front Desk</button>
```

How to resolve this?

How to add style of jQuery button UI to `Front Desk` button?

```
.frontdesk{
margin-left:178px;
margin-top:0px;
}

div.ui-datepicker{
    font-size:10px;
}
.ui-datepicker {
    width: 16em;
}

 body { font-family:Lucida Sans, Lucida Sans Unicode, Arial, Sans-Serif; font-size:13px; margin:0px auto;}
    #tabs { margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; overflow:hidden; }
    #tabs li { float:left; margin-left:4px; display:block; padding:10px; !important background-color:#8AE62E; margin-right:0px;}
    #tabs li a { color:#fff; !important text-decoration:none; }
    #tabs li.current { background-color:#C16CC1; !important height:18px}
    #tabs li.current a { color:#000; !important text-decoration:none; }
    #tabs li a.remove { color:#f00; !important margin-left:10px;}
    #content { background-color:#e1e1e1; !important}
    #content p { margin: 0; padding:20px 20px 100px 20px;}

    #main { width:1050px; height:500px; margin:0px auto; overflow:hidden;background-color:#F6F6F6; !important margin-top:0px;
         -moz-border-radius:10px;  -webkit-border-radius:10px; padding:0px;}
    #wrapper, #doclist { float:left; margin:0 0px 0 0;}
    #doclist { width:150px; border-right:solid 1px #dcdcdc;}
    #doclist ul { margin:0; list-style:none;}
    #doclist li { margin:10px 0; padding:0;}
    #documents { margin:0; padding:0;}

    #wrapper { width:1200px; margin-top:0px;}

    #header{ background-color:#F6F6F6; !important width:900px; margin:0px auto; margin-top:0px;
         -moz-border-radius:10px;  -webkit-border-radius:10px; padding:30px; position:relative;}
    #header h2 {font-size:16px; font-weight:normal; margin:0px; padding:0px;}


a:link {
color:#042953;
font-size:10px;
font-weight:700;

}   


/*demo styles*/
    body {font-size: 62.5%; font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif; }
    fieldset { border:0; margin: 0px 0 0 0;}    
    label,select,.ui-select-menu { float: left; margin-left:12px; margin-right: 10px; }
    select { width: 140px; }

    /*select with custom icons*/
    body a.customicons { height: 2.8em;}
    body .customicons li a, body a.customicons span.ui-selectmenu-status { line-height: 2em; padding-left: 30px !important; }
    body .video .ui-selectmenu-item-icon, body .podcast .ui-selectmenu-item-icon, body .rss .ui-selectmenu-item-icon { height: 24px; width: 24px; }
    body .video .ui-selectmenu-item-icon { background: url(images/24-video-square.png) 0 0 no-repeat; }
    body .podcast .ui-selectmenu-item-icon { background: url(images/24-podcast-square.png) 0 0 no-repeat; }
    body .rss .ui-selectmenu-item-icon { background: url(images/24-rss-square.png) 0 0 no-repeat; }
```

Comment: You cannot have space in id. Replace id="front desk" with id="front-desk"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As you said:**

> Top place Button inheriting the color from jQuery UI whereas down
>   place is from the custom body CSS defined in the page

It means you have a **id** named `Front Desk` in your custom body CSS which is overriding the JQuery UI CSS
So, Quick solution would be , find that `id` in your custom CSS and remove that or give some other id name to your second button.

or

**Add following line in your JS**

```
  $("#front").button();
```

**for button code**

```
<button id="front" style="margin-left:178px; margin-top:0px">Front Desk</button>
```

Comment: I changed the id ,still same problem

Answer (score 1):

you need to override jQuery UI style.

you can do something like this into css but this have to be loaded **after** jQuery UI css!

```
.frontdesk{
    margin-left:178px;
    margin-top:0px;
    color: red;
}
```

and into your html:

```
<button id="Front Desk" class="frontdesk">Front Desk</button>
```

or you can set with jQuery css to your button like this without using a class into your css:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.frontdesk).css('margin-left', '178px').css('margin-top', '0').css('color', 'red');

});
```

Comment: Color is not changing to that of jquery ui css

Comment: I need to add same color of jquery ui css .Because of some other css in the page it is not coming..How to do it?

Comment: How to specify it to jquery ui css button color specialy

Comment: you need to add the property color @user3622611

Comment: Issue is that Button is not showing with jquery ui css button color beacuse of some other css overlap from the page.how to specifically add that in style of button?

Comment: in style is overrided, like my example you can add it into a css loaded after jquery ui css or with jquery where you add the css property on the element @user3622611

Comment: I opted first option of ur suggestion.Still same result only.One doubt why other buttons are coming jquery ui button colors and this is not?

Comment: seems that some other css override it. tru to add !important to the property color into your css an be secure that is loaded after jquery UI css @user3622611

Comment: I have added my .css file ..Please tell me where i am going wrong

Comment: Why are my others which are on one line above are in jquery ui and why this not ?

Comment: in your class frontdesk there isn't specify color @user3622611